# liSQL Listener not starting

Tags: mysql, database

Im having issues starting the listener for mysql. It keeps saying refusing connection and I'm not sure why. I've done this only once before, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong this time. Also I put in the password field root because I assume that is the default password. Any suggestions.[image]